# Stuck on adding Search via FetchedResultsController, Diffable Data Sources and CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a UICollectionView that I'm trying to get a search bar working in it. I have gotten the bar to show up, but I haven't figured out where to call the function I created, I feel kinda dumb (been at it for a few hours, might be loopy). I am currently using diffable data sources and an NSFetchedResultsController to attempt to perform my searching. Here is my code:

My function establishing my `fetchedResultsController` and placing it in `viewDidLoad`:

```
func setupFetchedResultsController() {
    let request = NPCData.createfetchRequest()
    request.fetchBatchSize = 30

    if !currentSearchText.isEmpty {
             request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title CONTAINS[c] %@ OR body CONTAINS[c] %@", currentSearchText, currentSearchText)
         }

    let sort = NSSortDescriptor (key: "title", ascending: true)
           request.sortDescriptors = [sort]


    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: container.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        setupSnapshot()
    } catch {
        print ("Fetch failed")
    }
}
```

My code establishing my search bar and search controller:

```
private func setupSearchController() {
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
}


func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    guard let text = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
    currentSearchText = text
    setupFetchedResultsController()
}
```

I also have a variable `var currentSearchText = ""` placed in the top of UICollectionView Class, and the class adheres to the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating` protocols.

I am calling `setupFetchedResultsController()` and `setupSearchController()` in my `viewDidLoad`.

What am I missing here? The search bar shows up, but anything I search it doesn't do anything, I'm expecting it to change my collectionview to show only the results I'm searching for (if I search for the word "Sportscar" then it should only show cells that show the word "Sportscar", not case-sensitive either).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get searchbar text in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058311/get-searchbar-text-in-swift)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058311/get-searchbar-text-in-swift This might answer your question

Answer (score 0):

Call your update method from UISearchBar Delegate method

```
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, 
              textDidChange searchText: String)
{
   //search in database using SearchText and update your view accordingly

}
```

Don't forget to set your UISearchBar instance's delegate to self.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks- I figured that but where should I call it? Can you give me an example?

Comment: This is the link I had when working through it: https://schiavo.me/2019/coredata-diffabledatasource/. I feel like if you grab the GitHub repo he links there, it’s missing something. Here is the repo in question: https://github.com/julianschiavo/blog-example-code/tree/master/2019-06-25-CoreDataDiffableDataSource

Comment: You don't need to call func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, 
              textDidChange searchText: String), it is event handler and will be called automatically when user type something in search bar.